# Scraping with BS, when adding (extend) text to list results in splitting each character as a separate string? Why and how to avoid it?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, beautifulsoup

I am no expert, but I was able to find a way how to scrape data using BS and save it to CSV. I used the same approach on several different web pages and it was OK.
Now I have encountered into wild problem, trying to solve it and google it, but no luck.

This is the HTML:

```
<tr class="abc">
     <td style="height:12px"><b>Name:</b></td>
     <td>Mark Park</td>
    </tr>
```

My code is something like:

```
name_list = [0]
res = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content,'lxml')
name= soup.find("td", text="Name:").find_next_sibling("td").text.replace('\n', '').replace(',', '#').strip()
name_list.extend(name)
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':name_list})
```

But the problem is that when text is added to the list it separates every letter into new string.
If I do `print(name)` I get:

```
Mark Park
```

But if I do `print(name_list )`
I get:

```
[0, 'M', 'a', 'r', 'k', ' ', 'P', 'a', 'r', ' k']
```

Expected result would be of course this:

```
[0, 'Mark Park']
```

As I said I never experienced this before. Can someone please explain how to avoid this and why is this happening?

P.s. yes I know this with creating list and adding [0] is not the best solution, as I said newby here.

Thanks

Comment: you want to use `append` not `extend`: `name_list.append(name)`

Comment: Hey @Chris thank! Simple thing, it is working now.

Comment: since it's a `<table>` tag, have you considered using pandas? What's the url and I can show you.

Comment: Hi @chitown88, yeah when possible I always use pandas `pd.read_html(str(table))` but here I couldn't go with it, as table is different on each page. Similar but different. Therefore this was better approach for me.

Comment: What do you mean table is different on each page?

Comment: I am scraping different pages, as each person has it's own page. 
So there you have Person A: name, university, DOB, country. But if person haven't attended UNI at all, this row will not be present. And, what I am doing is, scraping multiple persons info and storing into 1 CSV. Because of these inconsistencies I used different approach.
Or you have better idea?